# How can I add a value (string) in the structure field?

Tags: c, string, structure

I have a problem with enterning a value (string) into structure field.. Can someone show me how it should look correctly? I wanna add a string (surname/nazwisko) from console's window into student1.nazwisko but i dont know how it should look. This is related to dynamic memory allocation

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5PXA.png)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct dane {
    char* imie;
    char nazwisko[30];
    int nr_albumu;
};
struct node {
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
    char nazwa[50];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct dane student1, student2, student3;
    student1.imie = "Arek";
    student1.nr_albumu = 374829;
    printf("Podaj nazwisko\n");
    //*(student1.nazwisko) = (struct dane*)malloc(20 * sizeof(*student1.nazwisko));
    
    //scanf_s("%s", student1.nazwisko);
    

    printf("Dane studenta 1: %s\t%s\t%d\n", student1.imie, student1.nazwisko, student1.nr_albumu);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No images of code please. Post the code as formatted text in  the question body

Comment: Registered minutes ago, Thats my first stackoverflow's post, so sorry for neglect :). Can you see it now?

Comment: If you want to use [`scanf_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160) for reading strings, you have to specify the buffer size after the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The member `nazwisko` is an array statically allocated in the structure.

To read a string to that via `scanf()`, you should specify the maximum number of characters to read to (at most) the buffer size minus one (this "minus one" is for the terminating null-character) and check if reading succeeded using the return value.

With these points, it will be like this, for example:

```
if (scanf("%29s", student1.nazwisko) != 1) {
    fputs("failed to read student1.nazwisko\n", stderr);
    return 1;
}
```

Note that `%s` format specifier reads strings until it hits to a whitespace character. If you want to read a line (until the newline character), you should use `"%29[^\n]%*c"` instead of `"%29s"`. `%29[^\n]` means "read at most 29 characters until it hits to a newline character" and `%*c` means "read one character and ignore it". `%*c` here is for ignoring the newline character so that it won't prevent further readings.

Comment: Ok, it works with Your snippet of code. If I have problems later i will write here. Thanks a lot man! :)